"Filtered" graphs are initially blank
When viewing the 2024 Developer Survey result site, on initial load, all "filtered" graphs appear blank:

Graphs without filters load fine.
Switching to another tab within the graph area loads the graph, as does switching back:

If I scroll to a graph while the page is still loading, that graph appears, but others do not:

There are no errors in the console.
Browser: Edge (Desktop) Version 126.0.2592.113 (Official build) (64-bit)
OS: Windows 10
Note: Users in the comments report similar symptoms on Firefox (desktop and Android), Chrome 126-127, and Brave 127.1.68.117 beta (Chromium-based) as well.  One user reports it working properly in Chrome, but not Firefox; another Firefox user reports that it went away after a refresh.  See comments for details.

I've seen this in FF on desktop and android

Happens on FF, does not happen on Chrome. I also mentioned it as one of multiple problems on the announcement.

The same happened to me, (FF), reloading did fix it, so i brushed it off as temporary issue when the results released.

Happens to me in Chrome 127 on some, but not all, of the graphs.

same as Ryan and chrome 126, searched at the time, yesterday, to see if reported.

Happens in Brave (127.1.68.117 beta), which is Chromium-based. Page reload fixes nothing (though sometimes some charts are revealed and other disappear instead), but switching tabs (e.g. "professional" -> "total") does. Charts are rendered for a short while (less than 0.5s) and then become blank.

I'd add that refreshing has not fixed the issue for me.  In fact, refreshing re-breaks graphs that have been "fixed" by switching the selected tab in the graph.

Blank chart issue can be resolved by making the browser window smaller (Firefox, Chrome works fine for me) - resizing instead of switching tabs

We released a fix for this. The graphs should show correctly now.

Looks good to me ;)
